# NullPointerException in JdwpPaquet

Tags: android

I am trying to run the following Android app, but I get a NullPointerException

Main.java

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Main extends ListActivity {
 String[] listActivityNames = 
  {"Text1", "Text2", "Text3", "Text4"};

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Use an existing ListAdapter that will map an array
        // of strings to TextViews

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listActivityNames));
        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
 }

 /*protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
  Intent myIntent = new Intent();
  myIntent.setClassName("com.utsc", "com.utsc.Announcements");
  startActivity(myIntent); 
 }*/
}
```

Console:

```
[2011-01-26 13:58:57 - ddms]null
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
 at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:573)
 at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:142)
 at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:65)
 at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:670)
 at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
 at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)

[2011-01-26 13:58:57 - ddms]null
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
 at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:573)
 at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:142)
 at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:65)
 at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:670)
 at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
 at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

Comment: Happening for me too, did you get past this?

Answer (score 4):

I don't care that this question is really old, this was happening to me and it took me a while to figure out.

Make sure you don't have any xml files open anywhere. I closed all my xml files and this exception went away.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your app and it seems to run fine. Here is what I tested:

```
package com.stackoverflow.testlistactivity;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;


public class TestListActivity extends ListActivity {
    String[] listActivityNames = {
        "Text1", "Text2", "Text3", "Text4"
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Use an existing ListAdapter that will map an array
        // of strings to TextViews

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                listActivityNames));
        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is not completely usefull, I think there might be more hints in your error log, but still:

I think your `getListView()` doesn't return an object. You might want to call `setListAdapter()` first, before you can do stuff with the listViews, but i'm not completely sure why that doesn't work in your case. Could there be an error in that call?

edit:
This seems to be in agreement with wat @noel just posted.